# What do you call it when your life has been lied about and events over exaggerated

Tags: family-law

I have recently found myself in a custody case where the other parent has lied and over exaggerated unfortunate events in our (mine & my girls life’s) to gain temporary custody. Some statements have a truth behind the event however it was blown so far out of proportion it’s not even a true representation of the situation. Everything has been misrepresented. would exploited define it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about the English language, not the law or legal process.

Answer (score -1):

> What do you call it when your life has been lied about and events over exaggerated

The legal terms for that include *hyperbole*, *defamation*, *misrepresentation*, and *fraudulent representation*. The last one is likelier if the purpose of the falsehoods was to abuse the law and obtain something to your detriment, such as the temporary custody.

Most important: If lawyers got already involved in your dispute, it is very likely that the kids' mother and you will remain stuck in family court all the time it takes for [lawyers to deplete your savings](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LPgUMxoxFD4). In the process, she and you will endure all kinds of lawyer-fueled vexations, not just the one you described. Hopefully your ex-couple and you can reach an agreement, and get rid of your respective "counsels".